# Windows 7 RTM disappears from boot menu

Tags: windows-7

I tried to install - actually, upgrade from 7100 RC - the Windows 7 RTM. Everything went fine, installation completed, and logon screen appeared - I entered my logon info (domain credentials)... and when I pressed Enter it said:

- logging off
- shutting down
- and then rebooted.

After reboot, there was no Windows 7 boot menu and no boot menu at all - it jumped right into old Windows XP installation that I abandoned when installed Windows 7 RC.

Note that XP is installed on C:, while W7 is on E:. This is how boot.ini looks like now:

```
;
;Warning: Boot.ini is used on Windows XP and earlier operating systems.
;Warning: Use BCDEDIT.exe to modify Windows Vista boot options.
;
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN /FASTDETECT
```

Boot.ini.saved has the same content.

Yes [this blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windows7/archive/2009/07/13/update-on-windows-7-rtm.aspx) states that "“in-place” (or direct) upgrades from the Windows 7 RC to RTM will not be supported" but RTM installer actually allows to performs this. UPDATE: yes, I did change "min supported version" from 7322 (or whatever) to 7000 in the installation .ini file. Thus, I do not blame MS or whatever. Just trying to find a solution.

So, is there any way to resolve this except clean Windows 7 installation? Is this a known issue?

UPDATE: here's bcdedit (from W7 on drive E:) output: - is there a way to use it to switch W7 on?

```
E:\Windows\System32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {830cc0c5-6cbe-11de-9e38-d784ddd4a91e}
displayorder            {ntldr}
                        {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 3

Windows Legacy OS Loader
------------------------
identifier              {ntldr}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \ntldr
description             Earlier Version of Windows

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {830cc0c9-6cbe-11de-9e38-d784ddd4a91e}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=E:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {830cc0c5-6cbe-11de-9e38-d784ddd4a91e}
nx                      OptIn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer on one of the forums (I've found it while in XP and now I'm in W7 so don't remember the link): got [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1), reinstalled Vista bootloader, and I'm in Windows 7 now.

Don't know what happened, though.